# why `1 in [1, 2]` is true but `1 in [1]` is false?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In javascript,

```js
1 in [1, 2, ...] // returns true
```

but

```js
1 in [1] // returns false
```

I stumbled upon this weird behavior. Confirmed it on my browser's console.

Why is it so?

Comment: `in` checks for properties, not values...

Comment: and thereby, `2 in [1, 2]` will return `false` as there is no value at index 2…

Comment: i don't see anything weird... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Relational

Comment: use `[1,2].includes(1)`, see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array is also an object.

Array looks like this:

```
{ 
  0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3
  length: 3
}
```

`in` operator looks for the property name in the object.

so when you do  `1 in [1]` it's false because object looks like this...

```
 {
  0: 1,
  length: 1
 }
```

Notice there is no key named `1` it ends at 0, also known as index.

you can do this too `1 in ['a','b']`, which is true...

So in short, Arrays in JS are objects and their indexes are keys in the object. The `in` operator matches with keys which happen to be index.

Comment: lol, I should've checked the docs first. Thanks

Comment: I believe it's common misconception, pretty sure I thought the same at one point. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because the in operator returns true if the value exists as a key in the object. In your first case "1" exists because the array contains the indexes 0 and 1. In the second case the array only contains the "0" index

Comment: with the kind of requirement that you have you should better use indexOf method e.g.

var arr= [1, 2, 3, ....];
var a = arr.indexOf(2);

like this